# Is there a way to IF CONDITION a expect statement in TCL?

Tags: tcl, expect

Is there a way I can IF CONDITION an expect command. For example in the below code, I am trying to ssh into a specific IP address and sometimes it asks me "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" and sometimes it doesn't. How do I make it so that **IF** it shows up I send "yes/r" and **IF** it doesn't, I continue on with my code?

```
set name="123.456.78.910"
expect "$ "     ;       send -- "ssh root@$name\r"
expect {
  "Password:" { send "password" }
  timeout   { sleep 1 }

}

expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" ; send -- "yes\r”
```

Comment: I didn't mean to close the question, sorry. Anyway you have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the purpose of the `exp_continue` command:

```
spawn ssh user@host

set prompt {\$ $}    ;# or whatever regex your prompt matches

expect {
    timeout {error "timed out connecting to host"}
    "continue connecting" {send "yes\r"; exp_continue}
    "Password:" {send "$password\r"; exp_continue}
    -re $prompt
}

send "do stuff\r"
# ...
```

**If** expect times out, the script errors.
**If** you get the "continue connecting" prompt, send "yes" and keep expecting things.
**If** you get the "Password" prompt, send your password and keep expecting things.
**When** you get your shell prompt, the `expect` command completes and you carry on with your program.